# Protractor - changing pages/views

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a test case in Protractor which loads the home page and then clicks a button that redirects to another page. In that other page I want to grab the value of an element.

```
describe('todo list', function() {

   it('should find the contact phone number from the home page', function() {

    browser.get('http://homepage...');   

    element(by.id('re_direct_to_contact_page')).click();

    var number = element(by.id('phonenumber')).getText();
    expect(number).toEqual('412-....-...');
  });
});
```

However although it loads the page it does not check the element value and the test case fails.

How can Protractor load another page to check a value?

NOTE: - I made up this example but in my real test case I am sending data from one page to another so I *cannot* load the page I want directly.

---

EDIT: STACK TRACE

> protractor conf.js Using the selenium server
>   at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub [launcher] Running 1 instances of
>   WebDriver
>
> Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   "[ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.or/1.4.0/ng/test"
>
> StackTrace: undefined
>
> 1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

Comment: How does the test case fail now? Provide the stack trace please.

Comment: @alecxe Updated stack trace.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the contact page is a non-angular page?

Comment: thanks, and both has `ng-app` defined on `html` or `body`?

Comment: html - plus I made a change to the conf.js to put rootElement: "[ng-app]"

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you might be facing a timing issue. Try re-structuring your test from this:

```
var number = element(by.id('phonenumber')).getText();
    expect(number).toEqual('412-....-...');
```

To this:

```
expect(element(by.id('phonenumber')).getText()).toEqual('412-....-...');
```

While Jasmine and Protractor try to resolve every promise before moving on, sometimes it doesn't happen as quickly as you would like. Putting the entire promise chain into the expect helps to enforce the resolution of all of them before going through the matcher.

Comment: Doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Have you verified that your element is being found with your locator?

Comment: how can I verify this?

Comment: Using your current test, output the element to the console. Something like "console.log(number);" should do it. If that comes up undefined, there's your problem. If the test fails before that, you have a problem with Protractor finding Angular on the page.

Comment: I know this sounds embarrassing but how can I check the console.log when the browser shuts down so fast? Alert doesn't work either

Comment: Open a command prompt and run it from there. That way the window won't shut down before you can read the output. Also, you can run it from your IDE and probably see the output there as well.